# How do I practice with multi_index of boost library

Tags: boost, boost-multi-index

Do you have any document or project which I can practice with boost:multi_index?

Answer (score 1):

You could answer questions on this site. Or look at them and think up variations or see if you can duplicate them without looking at the solutions.

A good place to start:

- search [`multi_index_container`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=multi_index_container)
- search [Joaquin's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213114/joaqu%C3%ADn-m-l%C3%B3pez-mu%C3%B1oz?tab=answers)
- or look into other top uses of the tag: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/boost-multi-index/topusers

Also there are a number of introductory online documents, e.g. https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.multiindex